# How to split Javascript code (bs4) using Python

Tags: javascript, python, beautifulsoup

So I have been having some issues when trying to scrape Javascript values from a bs4 code.

Basically the javascript looks like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var FancyboxI18nClose = 'Close';
var FancyboxI18nNext = 'Next';
var FancyboxI18nPrev = 'Previous';
var PS_CATALOG_MODE = false;
var ajaxsearch = true;
var attribute_anchor_separator = '-';
var blocksearch_type = 'top';
var combinationsFromController = {"163972":{"attributes_values":{"15":"40"},"attributes":[75],"price":0,"specific_price":false,"ecotax":0,"weight":0.6,"quantity":1,"reference":"IDP20059--IDPA163972","unit_impact":0,"minimal_quantity":"1","date_formatted":"","available_date":"","id_image":-1,"list":"'75'"}};
var comparator_max_item = 0;
</script>
```

and what I am trying to do here is to scrape the value `var combinationsFromController =` however what I tried to do is:

```
bs4 = soup(requests.text, 'html.parser')

for nosto_sku_tag in bs4.find_all('script', {'type': 'text/javascript'}):
    if 'combinationsFromController' in nosto_sku_tag.text.strip():
        print(nosto_sku_tag)
        for att, values in json.loads(
                re.findall('var combinationsFromController = (\{.*}?);', nosto_sku_tag.text.strip())[0][:-1]).values():
            print(values)
```

Which gives me an error of `Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 4112 (char 4111)`

I did realized that whenever I try to do

```
for nosto_sku_tag in bs4.find_all('script', {'type': 'text/javascript'}):
    if 'combinationsFromController' in nosto_sku_tag.text.strip():
        print(nosto_sku_tag)
        print("---------")
```

The outprint gives me:

```
var FancyboxI18nClose = 'Close';
var FancyboxI18nNext = 'Next';
var FancyboxI18nPrev = 'Previous';
var PS_CATALOG_MODE = false;
var ajaxsearch = true;
var attribute_anchor_separator = '-';
var blocksearch_type = 'top';
var combinationsFromController = {"163972":{"attributes_values":{"15":"40"},"attributes":[75],"price":0,"specific_price":false,"ecotax":0,"weight":0.6,"quantity":1,"reference":"IDP20059--IDPA163972","unit_impact":0,"minimal_quantity":"1","date_formatted":"","available_date":"","id_image":-1,"list":"'75'"}};
var comparator_max_item = 0;
----------------------------
```

Which seems to mean that the javascript code is as one code which I believe maybe needs to split, However I tried to use regex for it but it didn't help me.

So my question is how am I able to scrape **ONLY** the value `var combinationsFromController =`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following regex pattern to isolate the entire javascript object which is assigned to that variable.

```
combinationsFromController = (.*?);
```

Try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/IHtlB0/1).

E.g.

```
import requests, re, json

r = requests.get(url)
p = re.compile(r'combinationsFromController = (.*?);', re.DOTALL)
data = json.loads(p.findall(r.text)[0])
```

---

[image]

Comment: Wow thats crazy, Thats alot easier than I thought... but it did it work! :) Wow!

Comment: Yup. Pretty much :-)

Comment: Well I have no word here than giving you the answer! It did exactly what I wanted to do :)

Comment: Maybe I still have a chance, How would the regex work if a javascript starts by `var spConfig = new Product.Config({"attributes":{.....}});` ? :)

Comment: What do you think the regex might be?

Comment: `p = re.compile(r'Product.Config(.*?);', re.DOTALL)` was my guess but that gave me `Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)` :(

Comment: No because () has special meaning in regex. You need literal () for the javascript and () for the capture group in regex, so you will need to include and escape the literal () You also need to escape .

Comment: Oh crap! I didnt knew that but now it seems right, I thought the () that you provided in the code meant the parentheses. I guess I would need to practice abit more with regex but now it is easier to know that every character has its special mening!